# Concucsion? A mash-up, combination of ingredients

Tags: single-word-requests

There is a word I heard somewhere on tv but I cannot find a correct spelling for it. It sounds something like **concucsion** and means a mash-up, random combination of ingredients.

Comment: Please click on the grey checkmark under the bottom arrow to accept the answer that helped you the most.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As requested I've made this an answer.

> **[concoction](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/concoction)**
>
> 1A mixture of various ingredients or elements
>
> **Oxford Dictionaries**

Comment: The OP didn't accept it!? Ah, but you posted *after* RSFischer's answer. Tsk..

Comment: But, aha! You posted the answer *first* in the comments, and gave a link too. (Usually, experienced users don't answer general reference questions. They don't need the rep)

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I gave up looking at my rep after I'd been here a couple of weeks. Maybe it's time I looked again. I know I have privileges I don't use.

Comment: That's a cryptic reply, if ever I saw one. I don't quite know how to take that. Note, my first comment refers to the OP who asked you to post an answer, so they could accept it. They didn't.  I have reminded the OP how to accept answers on EL&U. I also found it hard to find a reason for closing the question, it's obviously off topic, but the OP couldn't very well look up the word in a dictionary, although the definition was spot on, how useful will this post be to future visitors?

Comment: I mean I don't care if the OP doesn't accept --  I don't need the rep. If the other answerer had given a link to a definition I wouldn't have submitted mine. As it is the other person seems simply to have ripped off my answer (a) without acknowledgement and  (b) without even bothering to pass on the definition I gave.  I certainly don't feel guilty about writing a more complete answer. I don't see that this is off-topic at all. The fact that you can't find a reason that it would be is surely proof of that. So I hold myself blameless on all counts.

Comment: I voted for it to be moved to ELL here's a thought. Why not expand your answer and mention something about spelling and pronunciation. The OP's guess wasn't that far off, although useless for finding a dictionary entry.

Comment: There's no reason you shouldn't vote that. I'm just surprised because we regularly get  vocabulary requests here. If the OP had simply left out the incorrect version and not mentioned spelling at all, it would have been a bog-standard one of those. I applaud the OP for giving as much context as possible.  I'm not sure what I should add -- could you give me a hint? What should I say about spelling and pronunciation? (Other than the spelling was wrong and the pronunciation was similar enough to tell me what the answer should be)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31148/discussion-between-chasly-from-uk-and-mari-lou-a).

Comment: I did not accept answer immediately because I went to sleep, just as Chasly was offline when I replied to him. Chasly is right, he was first and RSFisher only ripped it with no acknowledgment. Chasly, I suggest you post answers more instead of comments more often. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the word you're seeking is concoction.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U.This post would be improved by explaining *why* you suggest this term, for example, by providing a dictionary definition or examples in the wild. I encourage you take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.